# osm tile server with multiple regions

Tags: openstreetmap, tile-server

I've built a tile server with data for the whole country, as well as a single state, but I was wondering if it's possible to combine different regions (load multiple pbf files) into the same database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. According to the answer to a [similar question at help.openstreetmap.org](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/5389/merging-2-countries-with-osm2pgsql) you *first* need to merge your files with `osmosis`, *then* import the result with `osm2pgsql`. Merging can also be done using `osmconvert` I guess.